# How to show tr with number td in view mvc?

Tags: c#, html, html-table

I have data as list, I want to break each row with 2 columns. I tried so hard but it is not working. This is sample html. I have 4 data rows, it should show two rows, each row with two columns.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>TYPE</td>
                                <td>Blue</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr class='bg-red'>
                                <td>13:45</td>
                                <td>2017ABC-0001</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>12:45</td>
                                <td>2017WEX-0002</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>TYPE</td>
                                <td>Red</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr class='bg-red'>
                                <td>13:45</td>
                                <td>2017ABC-0001</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>12:45</td>
                                <td>2017WEX-0002</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>TYPE</td>
                                <td>Green</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr class='bg-red'>
                                <td>13:45</td>
                                <td>2017ABC-0001</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>12:45</td>
                                <td>2017WEX-0002</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>TYPE</td>
                                <td>Yellow</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr class='bg-red'>
                                <td>13:45</td>
                                <td>2017ABC-0001</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>12:45</td>
                                <td>2017WEX-0002</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is sample code

```
    string result = "<table>";
    List<string> listTYPE = GetTYPE();
    foreach (var item in listTYPE)
    {
        result += "<tr><td><table> <tr><td><table><tr><td>TYPE</td><td>"
            + item + "</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td><table>";
        List<Detail_Product> listDetail = GetDetail(item);
        foreach (var detail in listDetail)
        {
            if (detail.PO_NO.Contains("ABC"))
            {
                result += "<tr class='class='bg-red''><td>" + detail.CREATE_DATE + "</td><td>" + detail.PO_NO + "</td>";
            }
            result += "<tr><td>" + detail.CREATE_DATE + " </td><td>" + detail.PO_NO + "</td>";
        }
        result += "</tr></table></td></tr> </table></td></tr>";
    }
    result += "</table>";
    ViewBag.result = result;
```

What should I do?, I thought to check `if (listLINE.IndexOf(line) > 2)` I will break new `<tr>` but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you draw an expected result?

Comment: Are you see html code snippet ? .The result should be two column in each row (two row and two column in every row. which i want) , but in my ```result``` data , all them in one column (i have 4 rows , because each row with one column, wrong in here). Are you understand ?

Comment: Give me a idea, "how to break line row with two column in a row" (each row with 2 columns).